# Не добавляются строки в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
   $host = '127.0.0.1';
     $db   = 'users';
     $user = 'root';
     $pass = '';
     $charset = 'utf8';
     $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
     $opt = [
             PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
             PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
             PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
     ];
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
     $sql = "INSERT INTO users (nmail, npass) VALUES('nmail6','npass6')";
   $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
   ?>
```

Не добавляются строки в таблицу...Ошибок не появляется

Answer (score 2):

PDO на то и PDO, что сначала подготавливается каркас запроса, а значения подставляются уже в момент его вызова. Вот как это происходит:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO users (nmail, npass) VALUES (:nmail, :npass)";
 $request = $pdo -> prepare($query);
 $request -> execute(
     array(
         ':nmail' => 'nmail6',
         ':npass' => 'npass6'
     )
 );

 if (!$request) {
     echo 'Ошибка при добавлении строки';
 } else {
     echo 'Строка успешно добавлена в БД';
 }
```